# Pattern problem, It includes the text outside (.*?)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to get the link out of a bunch of HTML and im using patterns for that. The problem is that the pattern includes the text before and after (.*?). Should it do that? I thought it only includes the text between boundaries.

Ive modified the code a little bit and now it only includes the quote.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http://cdn.posh24.se/images/:profile(.*?)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(splitStrings[0]);;
```

[http://cdn.posh24.se/images/:profile/088484075fb5b4418f5cb8814728decab",...
that is the output, this is the expected: [http://cdn.posh24.se/images/:profile/088484075fb5b4418f5cb8814728decab

Comment: I think you pasted wrong links. The output and the expected output are the same I guess.

Comment: @SaeedEntezari No, the First one has a quote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http://cdn.posh24.se/images/:profile(.*?)(?=\")");
```

This sequence is called `Positive Look Ahead`. You can find a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups).

Comment: Thanks, it worked! May I get some explanation of that sequence of characters?

Comment: @GameDevCro I added a link. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

```py
Pattern p =  Pattern.compile("http://cdn.posh24.se/images/:profile([^\"]*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(splitStrings[0]);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```